# MySQL server not running as service

Tags: mysql

I Have Installed mysql-server as root with command :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

i have configured and changes too many things related to the mysql-server Now the problem is that Mysql is not working as service 
as it is not in `/etc/init.d`

I want the mysql server to be started at boot time means to make it the service.

Now what i have to do please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find chkconfig easy to use: `sudo chkconfig --list|grep mysql` but it might be an outdated mode of handling it. Most of my servers have long used it but I find my desktop Ubuntu didn't have it and complains if I use it.

If you don't have chkconfig, do `sudo apt-get install chkconfig`

To turn it on: `chkconfig mysql on`